# traefik: passTLSCert -> Failed to create TLSClientConfig

Tags: traefik

Isn't this configuration suppose to work?

```
#logLevel = "DEBUG"

defaultEntryPoints = ["https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"

[file]

# rules
[backends]
  [backends.backend2]
    [backends.backend2.servers.server1]
    url = "https://google.de:443"
    weight = 1

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "backend2"
  passHostHeader = true
  passTLSCert=true
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.default]
    rule = "Host:search.dev"

[web]
  address = ":8080"
```

I would expect to visit https://search.dev in my browser and see google.com (given that search.dev resolves to 127.0.0.1).
But instead I see this:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 443:443 -v $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml traefik
time="2017-12-05T20:39:54Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration file /etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
time="2017-12-05T20:39:54Z" level=error msg="Failed to create TLSClientConfig: no TLS provided"
time="2017-12-05T20:39:54Z" level=error msg="Failed to create RoundTripper for frontend frontend1: no TLS provided"
time="2017-12-05T20:39:54Z" level=error msg="Skipping frontend frontend1..."
```

I specifically asked traefik not to do the SSL termination: `passTLSCert=true`

Some more details:

```
Version:      v1.4.4
Codename:     roquefort
Go version:   go1.9.2
Built:        2017-11-23_10:53:58AM
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing worth noting is that `passTLSCert` tells Traefik to forward TLS Client certificates to the backend.  It does not disable SSL termination on Traefik as you are hoping it would.

In order for your configuration to work you will need to specify the certificates for Traefik to use.

If you are using local certificates an example would be:

```
#logLevel = "DEBUG"

defaultEntryPoints = ["https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "example.crt"
      keyFile = "example.key"

[file]

# rules
[backends]
  [backends.backend2]
    [backends.backend2.servers.server1]
    url = "https://google.de:443"
    weight = 1

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "backend2"
  passHostHeader = true
  passTLSCert=true
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.default]
    rule = "Host:search.dev"

[web]
  address = ":8080"
```

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer, as by your own admission you can't solve the issue entirely

Comment: You are correct.  I updated my comment to include a proper answer and example toml config.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @FrankHinek Maybe a followup question: Is it possible at all to just stream the TCP traffic to an backend, which then performs the SSL termination instead of traefik?

Comment: @Ich That scenario doesn't sound like it warrants a proxy.  If you don't want the intermediate device to proxy the connection a simple router or firewall would be able to forward the TCP connections to the server so that it can terminate the SSL session.

Comment: Problem with router/firewall: Without deep package inspection (which is quite expensive) I can't take advantage of the SNI

Comment: I don't know of a way to accomplish this with Traefik unless you put the SSL certs on the Traefik instance.  Since this is a slightly different question I'd suggest either posting a new question to Stackoverflow or joining the Traefik Slack team and asking there.